# How to validate select in spring dojo

Tags: spring, dojo, spring-webflow

I have a form with a dropdown with dojo decorations applied to it.  When I submit the form without selecting anything in the dropdown I don't get any alert or required message that the form is being submitted. Please suggest what I need to do.

```
<form:form id="payment"  method="post" modelAttribute="registration">
 <label for="proofId">Proof Type:</label> 
    <form:select path="proofId" style="width:110px;" id="proof" name="proofId">
    <form:option value="-1">Select</form:option>
    <form:options items="${typeofproof}" itemValue="proofId" itemLabel="proofType"/>
    </form:select>  
    </li><br />

Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
 elementId : "proof",
 widgetType : "dijit.form.FilteringSelect",
 widgetAttrs : {
        promptMessage : "Select Proof Type",
        required : true,       
    }
}));
<button type="submit" id="submit" name="_eventId_createRegistration">Register Me</button>
Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ValidateAllDecoration(
     {
         elementId : 'submit',
         event:'onclick' 
     }));
 </form:form>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the value of the default option to " " rather than "-1"? (https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/Select.html#id6)

Comment: can u send me a working example

Comment: i have tried but still i m not getting

Comment: This is with Dojo 1.8.3, also not with a form: 
<td><select id="nm_packaging_line" style="width: 15em;"         required data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Select" data-dojo-props='name:"nm_packaging_line" '>
    <option value=" ">* select *</option>
</select></td>

Comment: Hope it's readable... Also I don't see the required attribute anywhere in your code?

Comment: i need with form:form spring dojo

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842546/how-do-i-make-my-dropdowns-formselect-required-with-spring-and-dojo

Comment: try implementing you own `validate` function inside you dojo element, and check that the selected value is different from "-1"